# how to get data from two tables in mysql query with where Pk of one table is set as foreign key on PK column for other table?

Tags: mysql, join, foreign-key, query, java

[image]

The query I am using to retrieve data is as

```
"select sum(totalbill) as tbdb, sum(discinamount) as tddb, sum (billafterdisc) as tbaddb,"
+ " sum(totalqt) as tqdb,"
+ " sum(payed) as tpdb,"
+ " sum(balance) as tbaldb,"
+ " `customer`"
+ " from `orderacc` join `orders` using (`orderaccid`)"
+ " group by `customer` order by max(`date`) DESC";
```

I am getting error that `orderaccid` is not a column in clause.

Comment: Well, your orders table doesn't have a column orderaccid. You can use `using` only when the column names are equal. Use this instead: `from orderacc join orders on orderacc.orderaccid = orders.orderid`

Comment: @tombom Okay I tried what to said and this happened. Error
" 
#1630 - FUNCTION storemanagementsystem.sum does not exist. Check the 'Function Name Parsing and Resolution' "

Comment: @tombom Thank you for your comment this worked you can place this as answer I will mark it as right. Thanks again man!

Comment: Glad I could help. Posted it as answer.

Comment: We can't tell which columns are in which tables; qualify each column in the query with the table it is in.

Answer (score 1):

Well, your `orders` table doesn't have a column `orderaccid`. You can use `using` only when the column names are equal. Use this instead:

```
from orderacc join orders on orderacc.orderaccid = orders.orderid
```